# Graph Search Algorithms that are practically fast on dense graphs

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, graph-traversal, search-problem

I'm trying to do some research on graph search algorithms that are practically fast on relatively dense graphs. Besides the common ones like A* or Dijkstra's, what are some graph search algorithms that give a good enough jab at the shortest path while having performance advantages compared to Dijkstra's?

The graph is weighted. The answer does not have to be exact, an approximation is good enough.

Comment: Weighted? Is it important that the answer is exact and optional?

Comment: Great questions! The graph is weighted. The answer does not have to be exact, an approximation is good enough.